# Ambiguous Error while column name is used in order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have encountered one issue below

```
SELECT ColumnName1,* 
FROM TableName 
WHERE ColumnName = 'XXXXXX'
ORDER BY ColumnName1
```

From above query it throws error as Ambiguous column name Column Name1.

Even though I have not used number tables then too it throws error like this. Can anybody tell what the reason behind this.

Comment: Your select list contains `columName1` twice

Comment: It is because in ColumnName1,* one column name is coming with *

Answer (score 5):

Because the `SELECT` has two columns called `ColumnName1` -- one placed there explicitly and one from the `*`.  Here are some choices:

```
SELECT t.ColumnName1, t.*
FROM TableName t
WHERE t.ColumnName = 'XXXXXX'
ORDER BY t.ColumnName1
```

or:

```
SELECT t.ColumnName1, t.*
FROM TableName t
WHERE t.ColumnName = 'XXXXXX'
ORDER BY 1
```

or:

```
SELECT t.ColumnName1 as second_columnname1, t.*
FROM TableName t
WHERE t.ColumnName = 'XXXXXX'
ORDER BY second_columnname1
```

Comment: Everyday I learn something new, I always used 3rd option without even considering other ones, thnx(+1)

Comment: and in second option you do not have to use aliases ("t")

Comment: Note that ordering by ordinal position is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve an error we have 3 options:

```
-- 1. give alias to the column
SELECT A AS A_STANDS_ALONE, * 
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY A

-- 2. order by 1
SELECT A, * 
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY 1

-- 3. give alias to the table and used it in column call and order by
SELECT t.A, * 
FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY t.A
```